# ISAAC cipher in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, random, stream-cipher

I need to communicate in PHP with a client that is using the [ISAAC stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAAC_(cipher)). As far as I can tell, none of the crypto libraries available for PHP implement this cipher. How could one implement the ISAAC cipher in a PHP application?

(I have found a Java implementation of ISAAC, and have almost succeeded in porting it over to PHP. The only issue is unsigned right shifting in PHP. I wrote a method to do it, but the method fails when the number in the shift is negative.)

Comment: Misclicked on a tag. It's because I cannot modify the client and it's using isaac. I have to decrypt/encrypt to send data to the client

Comment: Given that my answer was accepted, currently has 17 upvotes and (presumably) solves the OP's problem, I don't see any reason to consider this question "too broad". Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [ISAAC cipher](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html) is fairly simple, and since it's written in C, it shouldn't be too hard to port it to PHP.  The only real complication is that ISAAC uses 32-bit unsigned integers with wrap-around, whereas PHP's integers may be 32 or 64 bits and get auto-converted to floats on overflow.  This isn't that big an issue, though, since we can easily work around it by applying bitmasks where needed to force intermediate values down to 32 bits.

Anyway, here's a fairly direct port of the ISAAC reference code to PHP:

> As of September 2017, this code is now also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/vyznev/ISAAC-PHP).

```php
<?php
/*
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISAAC random number generator by Bob Jenkins.  PHP port by Ilmari Karonen.

Based on the randport.c and readable.c reference C implementations by Bob
Jenkins, with some inspiration taken from the Perl port by John L. Allen.

This code is released into the public domain.  Do whatever you want with it.

HISTORY:
 2013-01-20: Initial version.  (Typo in version date fixed on 2017-09-19.)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

class ISAAC {
    private $m, $a, $b, $c; // internal state
    public  $r;   // current chunk of results

    public function isaac()
    {
        $c = ++$this->c;     // c gets incremented once per 256 results
        $b = $this->b += $c; // then combined with b
        $a = $this->a;

        $m =& $this->m;
        $r = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; ++$i) {
            $x = $m[$i];
            switch ($i & 3) {
            case 0: $a ^= ($a << 13); break;
            case 1: $a ^= ($a >>  6) & 0x03ffffff; break;
            case 2: $a ^= ($a <<  2); break;
            case 3: $a ^= ($a >> 16) & 0x0000ffff; break;
            }
            $a += $m[$i ^ 128]; $a &= 0xffffffff;
            $m[$i] = $y = ($m[($x >>  2) & 255] + $a + $b) & 0xffffffff;
            $r[$i] = $b = ($m[($y >> 10) & 255] + $x) & 0xffffffff;
        }

        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        $this->c = $c;
        $this->r = $r;
    }

    public function rand()
    {
        if (empty($this->r)) $this->isaac();
        return array_pop($this->r);
    }

    private static function mix( &$a, &$b, &$c, &$d, &$e, &$f, &$g, &$h )
    {
        $a ^= ($b << 11);              $d += $a; $b += $c;
        $b ^= ($c >>  2) & 0x3fffffff; $e += $b; $c += $d;
        $c ^= ($d <<  8);              $f += $c; $d += $e;
        $d ^= ($e >> 16) & 0x0000ffff; $g += $d; $e += $f;
        $e ^= ($f << 10);              $h += $e; $f += $g;
        $f ^= ($g >>  4) & 0x0fffffff; $a += $f; $g += $h;
        $g ^= ($h <<  8);              $b += $g; $h += $a;
        $h ^= ($a >>  9) & 0x007fffff; $c += $h; $a += $b;
        // 64-bit PHP does something weird on integer overflow; avoid it
        $a &= 0xffffffff; $b &= 0xffffffff; $c &= 0xffffffff; $d &= 0xffffffff;
        $e &= 0xffffffff; $f &= 0xffffffff; $g &= 0xffffffff; $h &= 0xffffffff;
    }

    public function __construct ( $seed = null )
    {
        $this->a = $this->b = $this->c = 0;
        $this->m = array_fill(0, 256, 0);
        $m =& $this->m;

        $a = $b = $c = $d = $e = $f = $g = $h = 0x9e3779b9;  // golden ratio

        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
            ISAAC::mix($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h);      // scramble it
        }

        if ( isset($seed) ) {
            if ( is_string($seed) ) {
                // emulate casting char* to int* on a little-endian CPU
                $seed = array_values(unpack("V256", pack("a1024", $seed)));
            }

            // initialize using the contents of $seed as the seed
            for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i += 8) {
                $a += $seed[$i  ]; $b += $seed[$i+1];
                $c += $seed[$i+2]; $d += $seed[$i+3];
                $e += $seed[$i+4]; $f += $seed[$i+5];
                $g += $seed[$i+6]; $h += $seed[$i+7];
                ISAAC::mix($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h);
                $m[$i  ] = $a; $m[$i+1] = $b; $m[$i+2] = $c; $m[$i+3] = $d;
                $m[$i+4] = $e; $m[$i+5] = $f; $m[$i+6] = $g; $m[$i+7] = $h;
            }

            // do a second pass to make all of the seed affect all of $m
            for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i += 8) {
                $a += $m[$i  ]; $b += $m[$i+1]; $c += $m[$i+2]; $d += $m[$i+3];
                $e += $m[$i+4]; $f += $m[$i+5]; $g += $m[$i+6]; $h += $m[$i+7];
                ISAAC::mix($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h);
                $m[$i  ] = $a; $m[$i+1] = $b; $m[$i+2] = $c; $m[$i+3] = $d;
                $m[$i+4] = $e; $m[$i+5] = $f; $m[$i+6] = $g; $m[$i+7] = $h;
            }
        }
        else {
            // fill in $m with messy stuff (does anyone really use this?)
            for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i += 8) {
                ISAAC::mix($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h);
                $m[$i  ] = $a; $m[$i+1] = $b; $m[$i+2] = $c; $m[$i+3] = $d;
                $m[$i+4] = $e; $m[$i+5] = $f; $m[$i+6] = $g; $m[$i+7] = $h;
            }
        }

        // fill in the first set of results
        $this->isaac();
    }
}
```

The `ISAAC` class constructor takes an optional `$seed` parameter, which should be either a 256-element array of 32-bit integers, a string of up to 1024 bytes (which is converted to an array using `unpack()`; see the code) or `null` (the default).  If the seed is null or omitted, the shorter single-pass initialization is used, which corresponds to calling `randinit()` with `flag == FALSE` in the C reference implementation; otherwise, the two-pass initialization corresponding to `flag == TRUE`is used.

The class provides a `rand()` method that returns a single 32-bit number, just like the `rand()` macro defined in Jenkins' [`rand.h`](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/c/rand.h).  Alternatively, I've left the core `isaac()` method and its internal result buffer `$r` public, so that those preferring more direct access to the generator can just call `isaac()` themselves and grab the output that way.  Note that the constructor already calls `isaac()` once, just like `randinit()` in the reference implementation, so you only need to call it again after exhausting the first 256 output values.

---

Here are two test programs, the first corresponding to the test code included inside [rand.c](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/c/rand.c):

```php
<?php
require_once('isaac.php');

$seed = array_fill(0, 256, 0);
$isaac = new ISAAC ( $seed );

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i) {
    $isaac->isaac();  // XXX: the first output block is dropped!
    for ($j = 0; $j < 256; ++$j) {
        printf("%08x", $isaac->r[$j]);
        if (($j & 7) == 7) echo "\n";
    }
}
```

and the second  [randtest.c](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/c/randtest.c) from the [ISAAC challenge](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html#challenge):

```php
<?php
require_once('isaac.php');

$seed = "This is <i>not</i> the right mytext.";
$isaac = new ISAAC ( $seed );

for ($j = 0; $j < 10 * 256; ++$j) {
    printf("%08x ", $isaac->rand());
    if (($j & 7) == 7) echo "\n";
}
```

The outputs of these programs should match [randvect.txt](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/randvect.txt) and [randseed.txt](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/randseed.txt) respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been porting and retesting and reporting a version that I found written in java. I had failed over and over until you just posted this.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no public implemention of ISAAC in PHP. It's not so popular, therefore you cannot find ready-made implemention of it in PHP.

You have to options:

a) Read the algorithm papaers and try to implement it in PHP and be the first who did it.

b) Use some proxies, there is some public implemention of algorithm in Java, Ruby, etc. You can call them via command line etc.

Comment: I have ported it over successfully, the only issue is unsigned right shifting in php. I wrote a method, but the method fails when the number in the shift is negative.